# Linux - how to distinguish two same lp printers

Tags: linux, printing, console, serial-port, cups

We have 2 lp printers connected to Linux Ubuntu machine. After system boot there are two files created: `/dev/usb/lp0` and `/dev/usb/lp1`. Unfortunately these files are created randomly and we cannot distinguish which one is which. When I echo text in this way:

```
echo -ne "test" > "/dev/usb/lp0"
```

everything works fine but of course I don't know which printer will print. We have tried using alias in dev rules (using info gathered from `devadm info -q all -a /dev/usb/lp*`):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", KERNELS=="1-1.3.2", SYMLINK+="dr_lewa"
```

In `/dev` there is indeed alias created:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          15 Apr 15 14:44 dr_lewa -> bus/usb/001/012
```

When I try to write to this in the same way as to `/dev/usb/lpX` error is given:

```
echo -ne "test" > /dev/dr_lewa
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

How can I distinguish two USB serial port lp printers and write to them in normal serial-port-way?

Comment: udev has persistent naming rules for storage and network interfaces.  You could  find or write a similar script for printers.

Comment: You are probably matching too often and attaching the symlink at the wrong level. You need to restrict the match to just when the device name is `/dev/usb/lp0`. Try looking through `sudo udevadm monitor -k -u -p` output when you plug the printer in to see if you can be more specific.